# Converting UIView with perspective transform to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, core-animation

I want to convert UIView with perspective transform to UIImage but I got image without transformation. How can I keep transformation?

I'm making perspective transform for UIView with following code:

```
    var rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 45.0 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 45.0 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    self.photoImageView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform
```

then converting UIView with perspective transform to UIImage:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

And as a result I'm getting correct image but without perspective

Comment: @LeoDabus same result

Comment: @LeoDabus         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        photoImageView.layer.presentationLayer()!.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
 let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIView method drawViewHierarchyInRect. It will render a snapshot of the complete view hierarchy as visible onscreen into the current context.

Try like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: @AntonVodolazkyi I already tested and it does work. You are doing something wrong. I will post a link with a sample project

Comment: I will waiting for your response

Comment: I did but it still the same, here is screenshot: 
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4-ymA67JSlvdmRCU2Z1WExONkU)

Comment: You need to render the view

Comment: Thank You so much! You saved a lot of my hours!